# How to set the `Set-Cookie` Header from AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, setcookie

I've logged in to a REST API, and it is returning the `Set-Cookie` header in the response.

However, if I try to make another request to list some objects, it's saying I'm unauthorized - please login.

I'm not sure what to do with the `Set-Cookie` header. Is there a way I can console log that, store it in a const, and send that along with future requests?

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the request go to a different domain? In that case, you have to set the `withCredentials` flag when making the AJAX request, otherwise cookies won’t be send with the request.

Answer (score 0):

By default, for non same origin request, browsers will not send credentials (such as HTTP Cookies and HTTP Authentication). A specific attribute has to be set on the XMLHttpRequest object when it is invoked.
You can set following setting in your `$.ajax` call

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

Comment: This has been added, and we also have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` set to true as well. I just found out Github Electron is running the app out of file:// so I'm going to try to start it in localhost with node and see if that makes a difference.